# History of computing/computation in higher education

Tags: computer-science, education, computation

A Google search for the first academic computer science program a couple of years ago cited a half-dozen programs in France and England that were considered proto-computer science. Current searches yield no such answers. Can anyone suggest an avenue for recovering the names of those programs? The earliest was in the 1800s.

Comment: At what point does automated calculation (Charles Babbage, etc) and process automation (Joseph Marie Jacquard, etc) become computation?

Answer (score 1):

There was study of computation without (analog or digital) computers. Initially, computers were [people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_computer) who computed. A more theoretical question is that of [computatability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability). If Gödel's answer to Hilbert's question counts, how about the [Göttingen School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_G%C3%B6ttingen#18th_.E2.80.93_19th_centuries)?